# WPF create a list of items that scroll vertically then horizontally

Tags: wpf, data-visualization, wrappanel

How can I go about creating a control that has items in item that list vertically, but only to the height of the control, then start at the top of the second column?

Sort of like the windows explorer look and feel.

I am using a `WrapPanel` at the moment, but I cannot figure out how to make it scroll horizontally...

Any help here is greatly appreciated

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose a `WrapPanel` with vertical orientation within a `ScrollViewer` with `VerticalScrollbarVisibility` set to `Disabled`.

Paste this into Kaxaml and you'll see:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
      </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid Margin="200, 100">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxWidth="200">
    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
      <Button/>
    </WrapPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: If you set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled, you don't need to set MaxHeight.

Comment: Fixed.  For some reason I forgot that `Visibility.Disabled` even existed.

Comment: works very well, although I had some initial trouble, I was using a Canvas instead of a grid, and the scrollbar did not show up when there was a lot of content in the wrappanel, why is that?

Comment: If you're using a `Canvas`, you have to provide an explicit size and position for child content.  `Canvas` is really super-primitive; you shouldn't use it for laying out UI controls in most circumstances because it doesn't do any kind of default layout; you have to tell it everything about where to put the child elements and how big they are yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds alot like a UniformGrid or a WrapPanel to me
check this [blog](http://www.wpfdude.com/articles/LayoutPanels.aspx), he has some nice demos of the built-in layout panels

Comment: The only problem with that is that the WrapPanel doesnt scroll, and I need it to, and Im assuming the same for the UniformGrid...